# How to allow the user ROLE_USER access to the SonataAdminBundle service?

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin, roles

I apologize in advance for my English.

Good day!

I really can not find the answer to my problem. I will be grateful for any help.

So. There is a project on Symfony 2.8. There is a module SonataAdminBundle + FOSUserBundle. I created several services: `User`, `Flat` and `Admin`.

Log in the admin area is provided with the presence of ROLE_USER and more. When you enter the admin area with ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN, all services are visible, and when you log in with ROLE_USER, not a single service is visible. Different manipulations with the code did not yield any results.

Maybe someone knows how to correctly grant the user with ROLE_USER access to the Admin service?

**security.yml**

```
 security:
 role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
 access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

**services.yml**

```
services:
  admin.admin:
    class: Flatbel\FlatBundle\Admin\AdminAdmin
    arguments: [~, Flatbel\FlatBundle\Entity\Flat,~]
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, label: Admin}
```

**AdminAdmin.php**

```
class AdminAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{

    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('id')
            ->add('userid');
    }

    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('id')
            ->addIdentifier('userid');
    }

    public function toString($object)
    {
        return $object instanceof User
            ? $object->getUsername()
            : 'Flat'; // shown in the breadcrumb on the create view
    }

    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        $datagridMapper
            ->add('id')
            ->add('userid');
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me if you you set up ACL or customized SonataUserBundle?

Comment: @staskrak
    
SonataUserBundle is configured and working fine. The user database contains standard fields, including the role field. Registration, authorization, etc. work correctly. There are no problems with this.
    
I have a page that access to unauthorized users in the controller is denied:
    
`$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_USER', null, 'Unable to access this page!');`
    
This solution works and the symphony requires that the user is authorized. But I do not have such lines in **security.yml** `security:
    acl:
        connection: default`

Comment: Did you try to configure sonata's dashboard? https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/dashboard.html#using-the-config-yml

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure role_admin in sonata_admin.yaml:

```
sonata_admin:
    ...
    security:
        role_admin: ROLE_USER
```